# Detect Scroll in Ember Power Select

Tags: javascript, ember.js, dropdown

I want to detect scroll operation in an ember power select dropdown, and only if it is scrolled, a particular value gets updated.

Checking the API Reference of the Ember Power Select, I saw scrollTo function, which doesn't get triggered when I scroll.

What can be done? Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `optionsComponent` property of [ember power select](http://www.ember-power-select.com/docs/api-reference). After that, you can add scroll event by using `jquery` in your custom options component. Take a look at this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/5119a951e6baa6869bdabca562955c58).